# Проект из C# + Python

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Возможно ли в Visual Studio 1 проект из 2 решений `c# win forms` и `pyton` собрать в 1 `.exe` и обращаться к этому `python` например как к статическому классу в `С#` `PythonFile.Function1()` ?

Comment: Нет, в одну сборку не собрать, а так познакомьтесь с IronPython. А что мешает питоновскую часть на шарп переписать?

Comment: @aepot за `IronPython` спасибо! А переписать мне пока не под силу.

Comment: Еще Python.NET http://pythonnet.github.io/